# google map api doesnt show on first jsp page load

Tags: jsp, google-maps, jquery-mobile, web

i have a jsp page writen for a school project, and im using jquery mobile and js code to show a business location....
the problem in my page is that the canvas used to show the map isnt showen when the controller servlet directes to that page. after refresh the canvas is shown perfectly normal.  can someone help me understand what am i doing wrong?
the code:

```
   <!DOCTYPE HTML>  
<%@page import="org.softwarelabs.mosheudi.hit.j2ee.db.Coupon"%>
<HTML>  
<head>  
<meta charset="UTF-8"> 
<title>coupon site</title> 
<% Coupon presentedCoupon = (Coupon)request.getAttribute("Requested coupon");
boolean addCalling = true;%> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.js"></script>

    <style type="text/css">
      html { height: 100% }
      body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
      #map_canvas { height: 100% }
    </style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    if (screen.width > 699) {
        <%addCalling = false; %>
}</script>
<script>

var geocoder;
var map;
function initialize(myAddress) {
  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 15,
    center: latlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
  geocoder.geocode( { 'address': myAddress}, function(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: results[0].geometry.location
        });
      } else {
        alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
      }
    });
}
function codeAddress(myAddress) 
{ 
  geocoder.geocode( { 'address': myAddress}, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          map: map,
          position: results[0].geometry.location
      });
    } else {
      alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
    }
  });
}
</script>

</head>
<body>

<div data-role="page" id="couponDetails" data-add-back-btn="true" style="background-color: #00B2EE"> 

    <div data-role="header">  
        <h1> Coupon information </h1>  

    </div> 

     <div data-role="content" data-inset="true" style="background-color: #00B2EE">

        <div class="ui-grid-b" id="couponInfo">

            <div class="ui-block-a" id="CtextDetails">  
            <h1> Coupon details </h1><br>
                <ul>
                    <h3> <%= presentedCoupon.getM_CouponName() %> </h3><br>
                    <p><strong> Price: <%= presentedCoupon.getM_CouponPrice() %>  </strong></p>
                    <p><strong> Expiration date:&nbsp;&nbsp; <%= presentedCoupon.getM_ExpireDate() %> </strong></p>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="ui-block-b" id="couponImg">  
                <p><img src="<%=(presentedCoupon.getM_imgUrl() != null)?presentedCoupon.getM_imgUrl():"Images/pictures/question_mark.png" %>" alt="coupon photo" style="width: 80%"/></p>
            </div>
            <div class="ui-block-c" >
            <a href="#"  data-theme="e" ><img align="right" align="bottom" alt="buy" src="Images/pictures/buy-now.png" style="width: 40%"></a>
            </div>
        </div> <!-- couponInfo-->

                <img src="Images/pictures/line.png" alt="coupon photo" style="width: 100%"/>

        <div class="ui-grid-a" id="businessInfo">
            <div class="ui-block-a" id="BtextDetails">
            <h1> Business information </h1>  
                <ul>
                    <p><strong> <%=presentedCoupon.getM_Business().getBusinessName() %> </strong></p>
                    <p> <%=presentedCoupon.getM_Business().getM_BusinessAddress() %> </p>
                    <p>  Phone number : <%=presentedCoupon.getM_Business().getM_BusinessPhone() %></p>
                    <%if(addCalling){ %>
                    <a href="<%=presentedCoupon.getM_Business().getM_BusinessPhone() %>" data-mini="true" data-role="button" data-icon="info"> Call </a>
                    <%} %>
                    <div id="map_canvas" style="width: 300px; height: 300px;" onload="initialize('<%=presentedCoupon.getM_Business().getM_BusinessAddress()%>')"></div>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="ui-block-b" id="businessImg">  
                <p><img src="<%=presentedCoupon.getM_Business().getM_imgUrl() %>" alt="business Image" style="width: 80%"/></p>
                <% if(addCalling){ %>
                <a href="useGPSHere"  data-role="button" rel="external" data-icon="search"> Navigate </a>
                <%}else{ %>
                <a href="https://maps.google.co.il/maps"  data-role="button" rel="external" data-icon="search"> Navigate </a>
                <%} %>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div><!-- content-->
</div>
<script>
    initialize('<%=presentedCoupon.getM_Business().getM_BusinessAddress()%>');
    </script>

</body>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably a loading issue, have you tried putting your google maps api include at the very top of your head-section? Btw you should not use element event handlers; instead fall back to the jquery way e.g. using the jQuery(document).ready() function to listen for the onload event of your page like so:

```
   <!DOCTYPE HTML>  
<%@page import="org.softwarelabs.mosheudi.hit.j2ee.db.Coupon"%>
<HTML>  
<head>  
<meta charset="UTF-8"> 
<title>coupon site</title> 
<% Coupon presentedCoupon = (Coupon)request.getAttribute("Requested coupon");
boolean addCalling = true;%> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">
  html { height: 100% }
  body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
  #map_canvas { height: 300px; width: 300px; }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
    if (screen.width > 699) {
      <%var addCalling = false; %> //declare your variables with 'var'
    }

var geocoder;
var map;
function initialize(myAddress) {
  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 15,
    center: latlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
  geocoder.geocode({ 'address': myAddress}, function(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: results[0].geometry.location
        });
      } else {
        alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
      }
    });
}
function codeAddress(myAddress) { 
  geocoder.geocode( { 'address': myAddress}, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          map: map,
          position: results[0].geometry.location
      });
    } else {
      alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
    }
  });
}
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var myAddress = '<%=presentedCoupon.getM_Business().getM_BusinessAddress()%>';
    initialize(myAddress); // call your init function from here
});
</script>

</head>
```

Since there is no inline css style I suppose you were just setting the map_canvas size directly on the element by mistake (your style in the head says width 100%). You should put that in your head style as well. You can also remove the unnecessary closing/opening script tag before `var geocoder`.